# Sitecore context not loaded in custom controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sitecore, sitecore6

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=407), and created this code:

```
using Glass.Sitecore.Mapper;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Sitecore.SecurityModel;
using SitecoreCMSMVCBase.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SitecoreCMSMVCBase.Controllers
{
    public class CommentController : SitecoreController
    {
        ISitecoreContext _context;
        ISitecoreService _master;

        public CommentController()
            : this(
            new SitecoreContext(),
            new SitecoreService("master"))
        {

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor can be used with dependency injection or unit testing
        /// </summary>
        public CommentController(ISitecoreContext context, ISitecoreService master)
        {
            _context = context;
            _master = master;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public override ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = _context.GetCurrentItem<CommentPage>();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Comment comment)
        {
            var webModel = _context.GetCurrentItem<CommentPage>();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var masterModel = _master.GetItem<CommentPage>(webModel.Id);

                if (masterModel.CommentFolder == null)
                {
                    CommentFolder folder = new CommentFolder();
                    folder.Name = "Comments";

                    using (new SecurityDisabler())
                    {
                        _context.Create(masterModel, folder);
                    }
                    masterModel.CommentFolder = folder;
                }

                using (new SecurityDisabler())
                {
                    comment.Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

                    //create the comment in the master database
                    _master.Create(masterModel.CommentFolder, comment);
                    webModel.CommentAdded = true;
                }
            }

            return View(webModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Models are identical with tutorial, so I will not paste them.

My route configuration looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CommentController", // Route name
    "Comment/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Comment", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

When I navigate to `/comment` I see this exception:

```
Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.MapperException: Context has not been loaded
```

I tried with commenting my route specification (as there was nothing about routes in tutorial), and then error is different (throwing by Sitecore CMS itself):

> The requested document was not found

Do you know how to load Sitecore context into custom Controller, and make this simple example work? I was looking everywhere but couldn't find any good answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method doesn't need Glass at all!

First step is to set your route in `Global.asax` file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DemoController", // Route name
    "Demo/{action}/{param}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Demo", action = "Index", param = "", scItemPath = "/sitecore/content/DemoHomePage" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Notice that controller is not taken as parameter, but is fixed, to prevent handling it by Sitecore. More info [here](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/11/The-Sitecore-Default-MVC-Route-is-not-a-Catchall-Route.aspx) and [here](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/11/Fun-Facts-about-MVC-Route-Initialization-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx). Notice that there is one additional parameter - `scItemPath`. It contains path to item which by default will be included in page context.

Having this route our traffic from `/demo` is handled by `DemoController` and `Index` action. Inside this action all you need is to add is this line:

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.Current.Item;
```

`item` variable will contain your Sitecore item pointed by `scItemPath`.

And that's all - it should work well now - hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is more a Glass setup issue, rather than an MVC routing problem.
To setup Glass, you need to initialise the context in your application start method in your Global.asax file.

```
var loader = new Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes.AttributeConfigurationLoader(
        "Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Tutorial.Models, Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Tutorial");

Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Context context = new Context(loader);
```

For other Glass-setup related stuff I recommend following the first tutorial on the glass.lu website.
http://www.glass.lu/tutorials/glass-sitecore-mapper-tutorials/tutorial-1-setup/

Comment: I found another way to get Sitecore context, and got rid of Glass completely from the project. But it's good answer indeed.

Comment: that link is now dead